# fscanf to structure array

Tags: c, input, structure, scanf

I'm trying to take some input from a text file, put it into a structure and print it out. The sample text file looks like this:

```
2
Curtis
660-------
Obama
2024561111
```

(Digits on the first number dashed out (for privacy), second is the Whitehouse.gov one, I called, they can't help me.)

Sample output:

```
204-456-1111 Obama
660--------- Curtis
```

(Formatting and sorting shouldn't be a problem when I figure out the rest.)

My question is labeled by the question marks below (in the first FOR loop, how do I get specific lines out of the text file to create the structures?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct telephone {
char name[80];
long long int number;
}

main() {

struct telephone a, b;
char text[80];
int amount, i;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("phone.txt", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%d", amount);
struct telephone list[amount];

for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    strcpy(list[i].name, ???);
    list[i].number, ???);
}
fclose(fp);

for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    DisplayStruct(list[i]);
}
}

DisplayStruct(struct telephone input) {
printf("%lld %s\n", input.number, input.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read one line at a time.

```
int lnum = 0;
char line[100];
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) ) {
    lnum++;
    printf( "Line %d : %s\n", lnum, line );
}
```

You can then use `sscanf` or `strtok` or numerous other approaches to pull data out of the string you just read.

I advise against storing your phone number as an integer.  Phone numbers are better represented as strings.

Comment: Whoops, the printf in my example was broken!  Have fixed it.

Comment: Oh! Haha, yeah I was wondering, this should help perfectly, thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that neither names nor phone numbers have blanks in them, you can utilize `fscanf()` to read this data:

```
for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    fscanf("%s %lld", list[i].name, &list[i].phone);
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

- You *must* check for conversion errors
- This approach is less tolerant to input errors (in case of using `fgets()` it might be easier to recover and drop the malformed entry - unless the record has wrong number of fields).

Comment: This ignores that the first line tells how many entries there are, I can't find a way to get fgets to work in the context of this program either. :(

Comment: Yes, you might know how many entries there are, but introducing a single blank (or an spurious line) in your input will completely mess up further parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @paddy, use a string to store phone numbers.  (Cope with leading 0s, variant length, #, *, pause, etc.).  Might as well also make sure it is big enough for a `int64_t`.
Note: The web has examples of 22 digits.

```
struct telephone {
  char name[80];
  char number[21];
}
```

To read in the data ...

```
for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  // +1 for buffer size as string read has a \n which is not stored.
  char na[sizeof list[0].name + 1];
  char nu[sizeof list[0].number + 1];
  if ((fgets(na, sizeof na, fp) == NULL) || (fgets(nu, sizeof nu, fp) == NULL)) {
    break; // TBD, Handle unexpected missing data
  }
  // The leading space in the format will skip leading white-spaces.
  if (1 != sscanf(na, " %79[^\n]", list[i].name)) {
    break; // TBD, Handle empty string
  }
  if (1 != sscanf(na, " %20[^\n]", list[i].number)) {
    break; // TBD, Handle empty string
  }
}
if (fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
  ; // Handle unexpected extra data
}
amount = i;
```

To write

```
// Pass address of structure
for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  DisplayStruct(&list[i]);
}
```

---

```
void DisplayStruct(const struct telephone *input) {
  if (strlen(input->number) == 10) {
    printf("%.3s-%.3s-%4s", input->number, &input->number[3], &input->number[6]);
  }
  else { // tbd format for unexpected telephone number length
    printf("%13s", input->number);
  }
  // Suggest something around %s like \"%s\" to encapsulate names with spaces
  printf(" %s\n", input->name);
}
```